# Rails 4.0.4 strong params and setting the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I just generated a new rails app and noticed this in my controller

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params[:post]
end
```

Noticed that `set_post` allows for the `Post.find` be accessible in all the actions. and now there is the strong params too which are post_params.

Can someone explain this further? What's with the new `set_post` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be having a `before_action` defined at the top of your `PostsController`.

`before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

It means that `set_post` method would be called before any of `show, edit, update, destroy` actions for setting the `Post` record on which you are performing an action.

This is just to avoid redundant call to `find` the record in each of these actions.